# Handling nil's in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, null

I get an error when using the map method on a nil object. For example:

```
x = nil
x.map{ |e| e}
```

Is there a better way to handle this than writing:

```
x.map{ |e| e} unless x.nil?
```

(I want the output to be nil.)

Comment: Where is the `nil` coming from? Could you change whatever makes the `nil` to make an empty collection instead?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here?  `map`  function can be used only on objects that have collection of values such as `Array`, `Enumerable`, `Lazy` sequence, `Vector` and so on. If you just want to check for nil value then what you have is a fine approach

Comment: Whenever you have a question that involves an error, please reproduce the exception message (normally omitting the stack trace) and report the line that raised the exception. In many cases that message will pinpoint the problem. I'm sure you got, `NoMethodError: undefined method 'map' for nil:NilClass`, which says it all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are using rails, you can use [`Object#try`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Object.html#method-i-try), which always returns `nil` if the object is `nil`:

```
x = [1,2,3]
x.try :map, &->(e) { e+1 }
# => [2, 3, 4]

x = nil
x.try :map, &->(e) { e+1 }
# => nil
```

Comment: Wow, there's a lot going on here, but I think this is what I need. It seems to be a short version of: begin <code> rescue nil end. I've actually used that long version a few times. I had to learn about "stabby lambdas" and their relationship with "&" but it was well worth it. My problem really is with rails since so many nil-based exceptions pop up when putting up a webpage. Thank you and good day, sir.

Answer (score 4):

Converting the `nil` to an `Array` would avoid the error, but you would end up with an empty Array instead of nil.

```
2.1.2 :001 > x = nil
 => nil
2.1.2 :002 > Array(x).map { |e| e }
 => []
```

Comment: Alternatively `x.to_a.map`

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski There is one good reason to use `Array()` instead of `#to_a`. `Array()` is more robust, because `#to_a` is not defined by most objects, however `Array()` works virtually with any object.

Comment: I appreciated this answer, even though I ultimately went with the other answer.

Answer (score 2):

Using `&&`, the second expression will be executed unless `x` is `nil` or `false`.

```
x = nil
x && x.map { |e| e}
# => nil
```

Comment: what if `x` it's not `nil`? what if `x` is ie. `0` ...  `NoMethodError: undefined method `map' for 0:Fixnum`

Comment: @yeyo, The title of the question explicitly mention `nil`. Values other than `nil`, `false` are truthy value in Ruby.

Comment: Your answer is correct and very elegant. I just was a little worried because this method will work as long as `x` is `nil`, `false` or an `Iterable object`; something very easy to forget I'm afraid.

Answer (score 1):

I like this more than @doesterr 's solution, but it's similar:

```
[*x].map { |e| e }
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
x ? x.map {|e| e } : nil
```

Outputs

```
x = nil           # => nil
x = false         # => nil
x= ['cat', 'hat'] # => ['cat', 'hat']
```